# Cloud-init for ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg works but not ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

So I'm trying to use cloud-init with minimal image ( https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/focal/release/ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.img ) but it does not seem to work at all. The exact same procedure works with the server image ( https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/release/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img ).

I'm using with meta-data and user-data with `genisoimage -output cloud-init.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock meta-data user-data`.

I then boot it up with `virt-install --connect qemu:///system --virt-type kvm --os-type linux --os-variant ubuntu20.04 --disk path=image.qcow2,bus=scsi,format=qcow2 --disk path=cloud-init.iso,device=cdrom --controller type=scsi,model=virtio-scsi --import --network network:default`

In user-data I try to debug it with just using runcmd in user-data to touch /debug but when booting it up manually afterwards to investigate there is no such file so runcmd doesn't seem to run at all. Keep in mind that the exact same procedure works fine with the server-cloudimg.Running `dpkg -l` on the minimal image shows the cloud-init package being installed.

**user-data**

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
 - touch /debug
```

**meta-data**

```
instance-id: iid-0
```

Comment: Does `cloud-init status` mention any errors? Does `cloud-init query userdata` show the userdata you passed to it? Is there a `Traceback` or `WARN` in /var/log/cloud-init.log?

Comment: So the problem seems to be that ubuntu minimal doesnt support cdrom so I used netboot `-smbios type=1,serial=ds=nocloud-net;s=http://10.10.0.1:8000/` instead and it works when i have a dhcp server but when I try to set it up with a static ip instead it doesnt work. I've tried passing a ip to the bootloader as described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360674/assign-ip-to-ubuntu-20-04-during-installation-packer-cloud-init-context but no success.

Comment: @Andrew Have you figured it out? I believe I have the same issue on `ubuntu-22.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.img`

Comment: Having a somewhat similar issue if anyone can help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428184/cannot-login-to-ubuntu-cloud-image-20-04-on-qemu-neither-console-nor-ssh

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumble the same problem.

Comment by [Andrew](https://serverfault.com/questions/1081072/cloud-init-for-ubuntu-20-04-server-cloudimg-works-but-not-ubuntu-20-04-minimal-c#comment1411371_1081072) is correct.
however we can still boot the system for ip assignment.

- create cidata.iso

  `mkisofs -o cidata.iso -V cidata -J -r user-data meta-data`
- create vm.

  sudo virt-install 
  --import 
  --connect qemu:///system 
  --name test 
  --ram $MEM 
  --vcpus $CPU 
  --disk path=/kvm/test.qcow2,size=10 
  --disk **cidata.iso** 
  --os-type linux 
  --os-variant ubuntu22.04 
  --network bridge:virbr0,model=virtio 
  --graphics none 
  --noautoconsole

in case want to still try netboot.
run `python3 -m http.server` from the folder with user-data & meta-data then append to virt-install cmd.

`--sysinfo type=smbios,system_serial=ds=nocloud-net;s=http://_gateway:8000/   //for network boot.`